# Dynamic SQL query for count data

Tags: sql, dynamic-programming

I'm working on an application that counts the number of employees in each department.

Here's my code:

```
SELECT 
    count(case when (JS_TITLE = 'Accounting')then 1 end)as Accounting,
    count(case when (JS_TITLE = 'Management')then 1 end)as Management,
    count(case when(JS_TITLE = 'Marketing')then 1 end )as Marketing,
    count(case when(JS_TITLE = 'HR')then 1 end)as HR
FROM EMP
LEFT JOIN JOB_STATUS ON EMP.JS_REF = JOB_STATUS.JS_REF
```

but the thing is, the user may add a new department.

Is there a better way to make this static code more dynamic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `GROUP BY` clause to group by `JS_TITLE`, then you must transpose the record into a column matrix:

```
SELECT 
    JS_TITLE, 
    count(EMP.JS_REF)
FROM EMP
LEFT JOIN JOB_STATUS ON EMP.JS_REF = JOB_STATUS.JS_REF
GROUP BY JS_TITLE
```